# Get all CLI parameters/switches from NSIS installer

Tags: cmd, automation, nsis, administration, silent-installer

Having NSIS installer e.g. Program.exe
Is there a way to get all CLI switches that current installer can process.
The purpose is to automate installation
I don't mean standard switches like /S switch for silent install
I tried to "unzip" Program.exe with 7zip - no useful info found about installer..
I tried to spy on it with Procmon - it's not launching anything on command line  - so no luck either
I know for sure that this installer receives custom switches ( one of them is /op=n )
NSIS docs are more about how to create installer..

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/S`, `/D=` and `/NCRC` are [the only built-in switches](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon) that exist in all NSIS installers, all other switches are implemented by the author of the installer and you would have to contact them if they don't document any in their documentation...

Comment: Thank You for confirming! I will try go 7zip 15.05 way..